# Control / override the build event in Visual Studio Wix Project

Tags: visual-studio, build, wix

While working on Visual Studio Wix Setup Project, sometimes we may have to override the default build behavior (just calling the Candle.exe and Light.exe by passing the regular arguments). Is it possible to customize / control / override the default build event so that we can control it? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you want to customize.  In general, the WiX build is driven by wix2010.targets file in tools directory which is imported to your .wixproj file.  You can change everything by replacing the targets file with your own.

For minor customization you may use the available hooks in the targets file by defining corresponding properties in your wixproj file:

[Candle Task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/candle.html)

[Light Task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/light.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please throw some more light into it, probably with some links / steps?